# VSTO File Not Found

Tags: vsto

I am putting together a VSTO addin for MS Outlook. The addin is designed to utilize a unmanaged C++ library. Access to the library is via a C++/CLI (CLR) project. I am receiving a 
    File Not  Found 
error when running the ADDIN directly. It appears that the addin has difficulty with the associated unmanaged C++ library. The library is completely packed within the C++/CLI project and nothing using it requires knowledge of the unmanaged C++ library. The strangest aspect of this situation is that If I launch the ADDIN from Visual Studio all is loaded properly. I've validated that all libraries being used are where they are suppose to. It is unclear to me why the addin would fail to launch (when not being launched from Visual Studio).

Note: I validated this by running a test where I created a C++ library with one class and a C++/CLI library with one class that instantiates the class from the first library. I attempt to connect to the C++/CLI library from a VSTO project. I get the file not found error. I felt this was the simplest test to validate / determine what was happening.

Peter
Peter

Answer (score 0):

The issue dealt with my making assumptions based on where things were placed. I had an installer that deployed the addin to the target deploy location. All files went into this folder. MY thinking was that if all the libraries are located within the same location they should all be found. This was based on the my thinking that an app runs and looks locally first for files. My mistake was that the app being run was Office Outlook - and it runs in a specific folder location. When I got the file not found I was thinking this can't be because the files are all together. BUT Office products when loading ADD Ins do not look in the location that the Add In is identified to be in (at leat for un managed DLLs - managed -- maybe different).

The end result was that the unmanaged DLL was not locatable because it did not show up in any of the seath locations of Windows. So the correct was to update the path to have the location of that add in. Which solved the issue of not found. What is annoying is that Visual Studio debugger -- looks to be working on the aspect of identifying DLLs where the application is being launched from. Which in general is fine -- except with VSTO the app being run is somewhere else -- but VS still looked in the project folder location to find the files. Making it somewhat unclear. This should not be occurring. VS debug should try or at least be configurable to operate in the context of the real world scenario. If it does -- I certainly was not able to find that configuration.

Peter